# pbi m query to concatenate a field

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Not well versed in PBI formulas but kinda know what I'm looking for.  I have a comment field that can be long so what I'm trying to do is

```
if text.length([comment] > 45) then text.range(text.combine([comment],"..."),45) else [comment]
```

Some of the comments field will be null as well.  I've tried different variations of this and just can't see to get it right.  Appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note, M is case sensitive, so text.length() Null and text.combine will not work. You have to use Text.Length() , Text.Combine() , null, etc.

Try this:

```
= try if Text.Length([comment])>45 then Text.Start([comment],45)&"..." else [comment] otherwise null
```

You can use add that as part of a new custom column:

```
let Source = #table({"comment"},{{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"},{"Bus"},{null}, {"Car Log"}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"comment", type text}}),
#"Add Custom Column" = Table.AddColumn( #"Changed Type", "Custom", each try if Text.Length([comment])>45 then Text.Start([comment],45)&"..." else [comment] otherwise null)
in  #"Add Custom Column"
```

Or transform the existing column:

```
let Source = #table({"comment"},{{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"},{"Bus"},{null}, {"Car Log"}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"comment", type text}}),
#"Transform Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"comment", each try if Text.Length(_)>45 then Text.Start(_,45)&"..." else _ otherwise null, type text}})
in  #"Transform Column"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Using the the first example I get "comma expected".  Looks right just not sure where another comma is expected.

Comment: Code works as written.  I assume you know you have to include the top code as part of a new custom column or column transform, you just can't paste it in .  Try the two full code examples by pasting them into home .. advanced editor ..

Comment: I had the last null capitalized.  Corrected and works now.  Thank you!  You weren't kidding about the case sensitivity.